# Having a refresh button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Lets suppose I am on screen2 on my application, and my application retrieves data from a database. I want to have a refresh button on it. So I am writing this code:

```
 b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Screen2.this,Screen2.class);
                startActivity(i);
        }
        });
```

where b3 is the button.My question is kind of theoritically: Is there any better way? Does this make my application heavy or causes any other problems to OS if I do for example several time refresh.

Would it be better to do the refresh for example at specific times? If yes, how I will write this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you could use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). much more efficient
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Edit: (thats only valid if you are using an ArrayAdapter)

Answer (score 0):

You should not restart the activity each time you want updated information: just update your views when the update button is clicked.